# How to change the folder structure of my GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

I am new to GitHub and I am currently learning how to use it. I have changed the folder structure of my local repo on my PC and I want to somehow push those changes on GitHub.
Essentially, I have moved all of my files from my local repo to a new sub-folder of my original repo. (as I am planning to add more sub-folders) now on my PC looks like I want, but not on GitHub.

I have tried to "Sync" the local repo with the one on Github, but this does not help. If I make a change on one of the files or I create a new file on the local repo and commit this change, it gets changed on GitHub, but this is not the case if I move all files to a new subfolder.

For example:

My GitHub is like this: File 1, File 2, File 3... etc.
On my PC looks like this C#> File 1, File 2, File 3...

I want to have this C# folder in both GitHub and my local repo.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you specify where you see a `.git/` folder? On your local machine, is it under folder `C#` or is it a sibling of `C#` ?

Comment: .git is within the C# folder.

Comment: What have you tried? This should be as simple as `git add <list of changed files>; git commit; git push`

Comment: I have copied the README files, gitignore and the.git folder to the new directory I have committed and pushed and the folder structure was changed in GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stated in a comment:

> .git is within the C# folder.

Note that all of the folders and files (as well as the subfolders of these folders upto any level within) in the same directory as the directory `.git` folder is in are what are visible to git. So, in your case, the `C#` folder is not visible to git since the `.git` folder is within the `C#` folder.

If you want the `C#` folder to be visible to git, you need to navigate to one of this folder's parent folder and `git init` in that parent folder.

You should also use `.gitignore` file and place it in the same folder that the `.git` folder is in to provide rules to exclude files and folders from source control.

tl;dr: You can go ahead and delete your current `.git` folder (after taking due diligence backup of the files currently under source control) and navigate to one of the parent folder and initialize your repository from scratch.

Comment: Great, very useful, I have fixed it! Thank you